# JQuery - Change integer to float with one decimal point

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point, numbers

Eg. if I give 150 //output should be 15.0
    If 1565 //output should be 156.5

Can anyone provide best code for the above logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.parseFloat()` and `.toFixed(1)` to set precision of one. The values provided in the toFixed() will set the precision till that value

```js
var a = 150;
console.log(parseFloat(a / 10).toFixed(1))

a = 1565;
console.log(parseFloat(parseFloat(a / 10).toFixed(1))) //to get the output type as number
```